# Quotes around long backstory narrated by a character

Tags: dialogue, science-fiction

I am working on a novel in which the characters talk to the protagonist and explain lot of backstory. It can run into tens of pages - essentially the entire story is told by the character to the protagonist and the reader is a third person learning about it in parallel.

My question is: what are the rules for quotes in these kind of conversations.

For instance (H: hero, C: a local character)

Page 1: H: So, how did you end up here?

Page 1 - 15: C: tells a 15-page long story ......

Page 16: H: "But, didn't you realize that what you were going after had these issues early on?"

Page 6-30: C: gives a long explanation with a couple more backstories involved.

In this case, I'd quote all the "H"'s statements. But what about the "C"s dialogue? How should it be written.

Thanks!

Comment: Patrick Rothfuss's *The Name of the Wind* is almost exactly this. He separates third-person narration from first-person flashback with chapter breaks.

Comment: Read Joseph Conrad's Heart of Darkness. Finest example of story within story within story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider writing the local character's story as a separate scene (and perhaps a separate chapter), with clear transitions between the two timeframes:

> "So, how did you end up here?" Hero said.
>
> "Make yourself comfortable, youngster," Local Character said. "This is going to take a while."
>
> # <scene break>
>
> It was 1953, and my mother had just shot the sherrif...
>
> ... tells the story in first person ...
>
> # <scene break>
>
> Local Character looked at his hands for a long moment. Then he said, "I know you don't believe a word of that. Nobody ever does. But swear every word is true."
>
> ... continue with "present-day" story ...

Comment: Definitely this. Such a story grants a `* * *` scene break.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Didn't think of this, but looks like this would fit my set up perfectly. Love your example btw.